# XML::Simple's "XMLout" method is converting attributes to elements

Tags: xml, perl, server.xml

I am attempting to use XML::Simple to update a few Java applications' server.xml files. While I am able to parse and update the object fine, the output from `XMLout` is giving me some trouble. It seems to insist on expanding all the original attributes into single elements which confuses my Java application when it starts up.

Here is an example of part of the XML:

```
<Server port="9000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="9002" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3"     URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
</Service>
</Server>
```

Me making a small change via `XMLin`:

```
$xml->XMLin("server.xml", ForceArray => ['Connector']);
$server_xml->{'port'} = $server_port;
$server_xml->{'Service'}->{'Connector'}->[0]->{'port'} = $http_port;
```

I then output my file like this:

```
XMLout($server_xml, RootName => 'Server',  KeepRoot => 0, NoAttr => 1, OutputFile => "server.xml");
```

Everything seems to work fine and look good in Data::Dumper but when I look at my output I now have XML like this:

```
   <Server>
   <Listener>
   <SSLEngine>on</SSLEngine>
   <className>org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener</className>
   </Listener>
   ...
```

I need everything to be rolled back up but despite my best efforts this has eluded me so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard enough to use XML::Simple for input, but output is very near impossible. I use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/).

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('server.xml');

for my $server ($doc->findnodes('/Server')) {
   $server->setAttribute(port => $server_port);

   for my $connector ($server->findnodes('Service/Connector[0]') {
      $connector->setAttribute(port => $http_port);
   }
}

$doc->toFile('server.xml');
```

Comment: Amazing.  It leaves the spacing and comments in place and everything!  Thank you!!!

Comment: Just as a quick follow-up.  How can I now append a new entry to the Service/Connector[0] array?  Thanks!

Comment: To add a Connector to a Service, create the Connector element using `XML::LibXML::Element->new('Connector')`, find the Service to which you want to add the Connector, then use `$service->appendChild($connector)`.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the documentation of XML::Simple on CPAN, it seems like the `NoAttr => 1` option in `XMLout` method is causing attributes to be converted to nested elements.

To quote the [relevant part](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egrantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#NoAttr_=%3E_1_#_in+out_-_handy),

> #### NoAttr => 1 # in+out - handy
>
> When used with XMLout(), the generated XML will contain no attributes. All hash key/values   will be represented as nested elements instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) like that:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $change_port = sub { $_->set_att( port => 1234 ) };

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'Server[@port]' => $change_port,
        'Connector[@port]' => $change_port,
    },
);
$twig->parsefile( 'server.xml' );
$twig->print_to_file( 'server.xml' );
```